# How to hide console output from IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When opening a project in intelliJ from git bash (i.e using idea64 . inside my directory) git bash starts writing some console logging that I've never seen before and I found no way of disabling it. I am using Idea 2021.3.2 Ultimate and git bash v2.35.1

Here's a screenshot of the logging :

[image: First screenshot]

[image: Second screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Copy `IDEA_HOME\bin\log.xml` into some location and add the following in `idea.properties` (Help | Edit Custom Properties):

```
idea.log.config.file=d:/some/folder/log.xml
```

Inside this `log.xml` file copy, delete all the console appenders:

```
<appender name="CONSOLE-ALL" ...
<appender name="CONSOLE-DEBUG" ...
<appender name="CONSOLE-WARN" ...
```

See also the [related bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-276732).

Comment: This is not fixing my issue. My problem is that once I run idea64 it takes over my terminal and if I close the terminal it closes my intelliJ as well.

Comment: Try running using `idea64 &` command line to detach the output.